# jQuery doesn't recognize identical textnodes (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, equality, textnode

I wanted to use jQuery to tweak the copy-mechanism. I noticed that when the anchor and focus nodes of a selection were the same, the corresponding jQuery objects (compared using the `.is` method) were not.

In Chrome and Firefox (Windows) the comparison fails in this example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#testdiv").on("copy", function(event) {
                    var sel = window.getSelection();
                    var $anchorNode = $(sel.anchorNode);
                    var $focusNode = $(sel.focusNode);
                    $("#logdiv").append("<p>The DOM nodes are" + (sel.anchorNode == sel.focusNode ? "" : "<b> not</b>") + " the same.</p>");
                    $("#logdiv").append("<p>The jQuery objects are" + ($anchorNode.is($focusNode) ? "" : "<b> not</b>") + " the same.</p>");
                    $("#logdiv").append("<p>Parent: the DOM nodes are" + (sel.anchorNode.parent == sel.focusNode.parent ? "" : "<b> not</b>") + " the same.</p>");
                    $("#logdiv").append("<p>Parent: the jQuery objects are" + ($anchorNode.parent().is($focusNode.parent() ) ? "" : "<b> not</b>") + " the same.</p>");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="testdiv">
        Select some text inside this div and press Ctrl+C.
    </div>
    <div id="logdiv" style="border: 1pt solid black;"><p><i>Log</i></p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I prepared a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cfrings/sh2ke2a8/)  to illustrate this, but couldn't reproduce it there.

So I tried with SO's snippet widget. It works again:

```js
$(function () {
                $("#testdiv").on("copy", function(event) {
                    var sel = window.getSelection();
                    var $anchorNode = $(sel.anchorNode);
                    var $focusNode = $(sel.focusNode);
                    $("#logdiv").append("<p>The DOM nodes are" + (sel.anchorNode == sel.focusNode ? "" : "<b> not</b>") + " the same.</p>");
                    $("#logdiv").append("<p>The jQuery objects are" + ($anchorNode.is($focusNode) ? "" : "<b> not</b>") + " the same.</p>");
                    $("#logdiv").append("<p>Parent: the DOM nodes are" + (sel.anchorNode.parent == sel.focusNode.parent ? "" : "<b> not</b>") + " the same.</p>");
                    $("#logdiv").append("<p>Parent: the jQuery objects are" + ($anchorNode.parent().is($focusNode.parent() ) ? "" : "<b> not</b>") + " the same.</p>");
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testdiv">
        Select some text inside this div and press Ctrl+C.
    </div>
    <div id="logdiv" style="border: 1pt solid black;"><p><i>Log</i></p></div>
```

Any ideas on what's happening?

Comment: Yes, but with the standalone HTML source? That's where it fails for me.

Comment: indeed! Tried it now locally.

Comment: Shouldn't you move the script to the end of the body?

Comment: I managed to reproduce it in jsFiddle by placing the `<script>` **above** (like i.e: page `head`) ... https://jsfiddle.net/sh2ke2a8/2/ - Strange, your  code already uses the `DOM ready` shorthand but anyways it fails if placed in `<head>`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Well done! Is this a bug or is there some hidden reason I simply don't understand?